# Heroku and localhost POST disparity

Tags: php, python, heroku

I'm trying to write a Flask application that incorporates a PHP script via a POST request using the requests module. I've had success on my local machine where I post

```
requests.post("http://localhost/webapp/templates/script.php", data=blah)
```

and everything goes as expected. However, when I push my code to Heroku, the post request no longer works - instead, I'm redirected to

```
http://mysite/php_post
```

and get a

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to be posting the data to your heroku application

```
requests.post("http://localhost/webapp/templates/script.php", data=blah)
```

should be

```
requests.post("http://mysite/webapp/templates/script.php", data=blah)
```

Comment: I just tried this to no avail. My URL was changed to:

    http://myapp.herokuapp.com/phpscript

and I was given an Application error. I've tried setting the run setting to 0.0.0.0 or something along those lines, but that didn't work either. I'm also very confident in my file path, since I actually ran the bash command and descended into the right directory where the file is located.